# Hive: NoViableAltException(283@[]) and Parse Exception

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I created the following table in hive.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS employee (
   eid int,
   name String,
   salary String,
   destination String
 )
 COMMENT ‘Employee details’
 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ‘\t’
 LINES TERMINATED BY ‘\n’
 STORED AS TEXTFILE;
```

The table is created successfully. I am trying to do the following insert

```
insert into TABLE employee (eid,name,salary,destination) VALUES (1,'avi','100000','boston');
```

However, I am getting the following error messages.

```
NoViableAltException(283@[])
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.regularBody(HiveParser.java:39678)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpressionBody(HiveParser.java:38904)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.queryStatementExpression(HiveParser.java:38780)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.execStatement(HiveParser.java:1514)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.HiveParser.statement(HiveParser.java:1052)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:199)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseDriver.parse(ParseDriver.java:166)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:389)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compile(Driver.java:303)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.compileInternal(Driver.java:1067)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1129)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1004)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:994)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLocalCmd(CliDriver.java:201)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processCmd(CliDriver.java:153)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.processLine(CliDriver.java:364)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.executeDriver(CliDriver.java:712)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:631)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:570)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
FAILED: ParseException line 1:27 cannot recognize input near '(' 'eid' ',' in statement
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO employee select 1, 'avi', '100000', 'boston';
```

It seems your version does not support `insert` columns list nor `values`.

P.s.
The error message is very clear.
You should focus on the last line.

Answer (score 1):

Remember you need quotation marks as you are trying to insert Strings. Also, the field names are not necessary as you are inserting a value for all fields in your table. You might simply try the following:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE employee
VALUES (1, 'avi', '100000', 'boston');
```

Comment: It has worked for me at home. You might want to take a look at the Hive documentation: [link](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML#LanguageManualDML-InsertingvaluesintotablesfromSQL). Note that the above is only available from Hive version 0.14. If you are running an older one, you need to load data either from a file or selecting from another table.

Answer (score -1):

You can't insert the data like this or insert command because insert command use in SQL.

For loading data into hive you have to create a one text file and you have to upload that file using load command.

For example

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH  'YOUR TXT FILE LOCATION' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE TABLENAME;
```